# How do I exclude the thread pool mapping time and just get time taken for the API requests only

Tags: python, parallel-processing, timer

I have a code that runs 5 API calls in a single iteration using a parallel method. Then I repeat  this iteration about a 1000 times. The problem with my output is that the time taken for each iteration  is roughly 1 second. Now if I were to run my code in parallel, then it would make sense that each iteration should average around 0.2~0.4 secs since they are supposed to execute simultaneously. Then I did an experiment to prove that I'm running it in a parallel method by running it sequentially. The average time for an iteration was 3-4 secs. After thinking about it, I realised I start the timer right before the pool mapping process which inputs the call_API function and thus the time taken would have included the mapping process. Not to mention, the timer also takes into account the time taken to validate the response coming from call_API function. Hence I was wondering if the code could be modified to just time the API requests instead of the whole process.

```
#Method 2: Multithreading

 import concurrent.futures 
 import requests 
 import random
 import pandas as pd
 import time     

 #Function to determine validity of the API response 
 def call_api(url):
     try:
         response = requests.get(url)
         return response.status_code == 200
     except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
         return False

 # Load the DataFrame from your dataset
 df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\jose.moquiambo\Bulk Calling APIs\sales_confidential.csv")  

# Number of iterations
num_iterations = 100

# Create an empty DataFrame to store the results
results_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Iteration', 'Pass', 'Time Taken'])

# Variables for tracking min, max, and total time
min_time = float('inf')
max_time = float('-inf')
total_time = 0

def process_iteration(iteration):
    # Get a random sample of URLs from the DataFrame
    random_urls = df['url'].sample(n=5).tolist()

    # Start timer
    start_time = time.time()

    # Execute API calls concurrently using ThreadPoolExecutor
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        results = executor.map(call_api, random_urls)

    # Stop timer
    end_time = time.time()

    # Calculate the time taken for this iteration# 
    iteration_time = end_time - start_time

    # Update min, max, and total time
    global min_time, max_time, total_time
    min_time = min(min_time, iteration_time)
    max_time = max(max_time, iteration_time)
    total_time += iteration_time

    # Check if any API call was not successful in this iteration
    passed = 'Y' if all(results) else 'N'

    # Add the iteration results to the DataFrame
    results_df.loc[iteration] = [iteration, passed , iteration_time]

    # Run the iterations
    for i in range(1, num_iterations + 1):
        process_iteration(i)

    # Calculate average time per iteration
    avg_time = total_time / num_iterations

    # Display the results DataFrame
    print(results_df)

    # Summary statistics
    print("Minimum time taken:", min_time)
    print("Maximum time taken:", max_time)
    print("Average time per iteration:", avg_time)
    print("Y stands for error-free response and N for errors")
```

## Output

```
     Iteration Pass  Time Taken
 1           1    Y    1.123318
 2           2    Y    1.122956
 3           3    Y    1.367392
 4           4    Y    1.064120
 5           5    Y    1.072951
 6           6    Y    1.026620
 7           7    Y    1.573418
 8           8    Y    1.039701
 9           9    Y    1.095653
 10         10    Y    0.983577
 Minimum time taken: 0.9835765361785889
 Maximum time taken: 1.573418140411377
 Average time per iteration: 1.1469704866409303
 Y stands for error-free response and N for err
```

Comment: Do the timing in call_api() and return the duration which you can then process by iterating over the generator returned by executor.map()

Comment: I tried that.... I used return response.elapsed.total_seconds() inside the call_api function and there is no significant difference. I even used a timer in the call_api function and still no difference in results.

Answer (score 0):

We could just move the timer inside the `call_api` function, it will starts just before the API request is made and ends right after the response is received.

```
from datetime import datetime

def call_api(url):
    start_time = datetime.now()
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        end_time = datetime.now()
        delta = end_time - start_time
        return response.status_code == 200, delta.total_seconds()
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        end_time = datetime.now()
        delta = end_time - start_time
        return False, delta.total_seconds()

def process_iteration(iteration):
    # Get a random sample of URLs from the DataFrame
    random_urls = df['url'].sample(n=5).tolist()

    # Execute API calls concurrently using ThreadPoolExecutor
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        results = executor.map(call_api, random_urls)

    # Process the results
    iteration_time = 0.0
    passed = True
    for result, elapsed in results:
        passed = passed and result
        iteration_time += elapsed

    # Update min, max, and total time
    global min_time, max_time, total_time
    min_time = min(min_time, iteration_time)
    max_time = max(max_time, iteration_time)
    total_time += iteration_time

    # Check if any API call was not successful in this iteration
    passed = 'Y' if passed else 'N'

    # Add the iteration results to the DataFrame
    results_df.loc[iteration] = [iteration, passed, iteration_time]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method does not work and only worsens the time taken by like 3 seconds per average iteration